# How to award a bounty to a comment?

Tags: support, comments, bounty

I would like to ask how to award a bounty if the answer to my question came from a comment.

I could find a solution to my question in a comment from Lorenzo Busetto. From his suggestion, other information from a blog post and some previous work I could write a script solving my problem. I have posted and accepted my answer but I don't think I should award my own answer. How do I give credit to the comment? I have cited the comment in my answer but I can't award the bounty to the comment.

You can see the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41117942/709777).

What should I do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You *can't* award the bounty to a comment; that is technically not possible. Comments are second class citizens, meant to store temporary information or information that isn't worth enough to be kept indefinitely. Information that is, should be put into the question or an answer.

What you could do is ask the commenter to expand his comment into an actual answer, to which you then award the bounty. If he doesn't – too bad.

Comment: You should have answered this question in a comment. Because irony.